# iOS app. get Facebook friends in alphabetical order

Tags: ios, facebook

I have integrated the iOs Facebook API into my app successfully.
Now, I want to get the Friends of the users.
To get it I use:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

And I implement a the delegate method to recieved it:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    uids = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"dictionary %@",result);
        result=[result objectForKey:@"data"];
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) 

            for(int i=0;i<[result count];i++){

                NSDictionary *result2=[result objectAtIndex:i];
                /*NSLog(@"resultq:%@",result2);

                NSString *result1=[result2 objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSLog(@"uid:%@",result1);*/

                Friend *f = [[Friend alloc] initWithDictionary:result2];
                [uids addObject:f];
                [f release];
            }
        NSLog(@"uids %@",uids);    
    }
}
```

So I create the object Friend with every Friend of the user.
I get the friends correctly but with a random order.

The question is, there is any way to receive the user's friends in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of receiving them in Alphabetical order, why don't you just re-arrange the array of Friends once you have downloaded all of them. This is the best way to compare an array and sort it alphabetically.

```
sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

But if you want to compare the array by an attribute / variable of the Friends class i.e Name, you can do it the following way:

```
sortedArray = [anArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(name)];
```

Comment: What you say was useful. Thnks, thats my final code:  NSSortDescriptor *alphaDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"friendName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [uids sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:alphaDesc, nil]]; 
    [alphaDesc release], alphaDesc = nil;